# captionof{lstlisting} Listingsnumber not in caption shown

Tags: listings, captions

Hi there having another problem.
In the following Minimal Example a listing with captionof doesnt show the Listings Number in the Caption :(

```
\documentclass[
  11pt, % Schriftgröße
  DIV10,
  ngerman, % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
  a4paper, % Papierformat
  oneside, % einseitiges Dokument
  titlepage, % es wird eine Titelseite verwendet
  parskip=half, % Abstand zwischen Absätzen (halbe Zeile)
  headings=normal, % Größe der Überschriften verkleinern
  listof=totoc, % Verzeichnisse im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
  bibliography=totoc, % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
  index=totoc, % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
  captions=tableheading, % Beschriftung von Tabellen unterhalb ausgeben
  %draft % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
  final % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\definecolor{bluegray}{RGB}{235,235,250}
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colComments}{RGB}{108,226,108}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{navy}{RGB}{0,0,128}
\lstset{
  float=hbp,
  basicstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier},
  keywordstyle=\color{colKeys},
  stringstyle=\color{colString},
  commentstyle=\color{colComments},
  columns=flexible,
  tabsize=2,
  frame=single,
  extendedchars=true,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\small,
  breaklines=true,
  backgroundcolor=\color{bluegray},
  breakautoindent=true
}


\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=footnotesize]{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain} 

\usepackage{capt-of}


\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=5pt, breaklines=true}
\lstset{emph={square}, emphstyle=\color{red}, emph={[2]root,base}, emphstyle={[2]\color{blue}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \captionof{lstlisting}[ListingsCaption]{ListingsCaption CITE}
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Xml,label=lst:ListingsLabel]
      <style name="MyStyle">
        <color>#b0b0ff</color>
      </style>
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Any idea what went wrong?

```
*File List*
scrreprt.cls 2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty 2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
scrbase.sty 2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
keyval.sty 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty 2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty 2011/03/23 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo 2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty 2011/04/02 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (type area)
listings.sty 2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
lstmisc.sty 2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg 2007/02/22 1.4 listings configuration
xcolor.sty 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
ltxcmds.sty 2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
caption.sty 2010/01/09 v3.1m Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty 2010/01/14 v3.1m caption3 kernel (AR)
capt-of.sty 2009/12/29 v0.2 standard captions outside of floats
supp-pdf.mkii
lstlang1.sty 2004/09/05 1.3 listings language file
lstmisc.sty 2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
omlcmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
***********
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In relation to your edit (added a file list):

As you can see my packages are newer. So make an update of your distribution.

**Originial**

Your examples works fine if I remove the command `\smaller`.  With this setting I get the following output:

[image]

If you want to use the command `\smaller` you have to load the package `relsize`. However your combination of `\small\smaller` makes no sense.

Here's my file list:

```
 *File List*
scrreprt.cls    2012/03/08 v3.10a KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty    2012/03/08 v3.10a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2012/03/08 v3.10a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2011/05/30 v3.09a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2012/03/08 v3.10a KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2012/03/08 v3.10a KOMA-Script package (type area)
listings.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2007/02/22 1.4 listings configuration
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
 caption.sty    2012/02/19 v3.2f Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2012/01/12 v1.4b caption3 kernel (AR)
 capt-of.sty    2009/12/29 v0.2 standard captions outside of floats
supp-pdf.mkii
lstlang1.sty    2004/09/05 1.3 listings language file
 lstmisc.sty    2007/02/22 1.4 (Carsten Heinz)
```

PS: your example isn't minimal

Comment: Why do you say "I know it's a comment"? The problem was in fact the `\smaller` command, so your suggestion solves the issue.

Comment: But the OP is not loading `relsize`, so \smaller will produce an error.

Comment: Not for me :( 
Removed the smaller but didnt worked either.
I updated the initial post with my changes and made a picture

Comment: still not working. Filelist update in initial post

Comment: @kitingChris: are you sure that you get the image using the *exact* same code that appears in your question?

Comment: If updating the TeX distribution is not an option one could try: Don't use `\usepackage{capt-of}`. This has no effect when used with actual versions of the `caption` package anyway, but will overwrite the definition of the `caption` package when used with older versions. If this does not help, try adding `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{labelformat=plain}` to your document preamble.

Comment: all packages are now updated.
complete log: http://pastebin.com/f9v9hC9K

Comment: sorry I hit enter. Complete log: http://pastebin.com/f9v9hC9K still not working. If capt-of wont work I need alternatives cause I have citetations in my caption that I dont want in the list of listings

Comment: Using MikTex 2.9 on Windows and it told me after an update that now all packages are up-to date.

Is there a different solution to get a listing with caption, number in label and the citation not shown in list of listings?

Comment: finally I found out what went wrong. Explanation follows

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Updating was the right solution.

For those who still have same problems:
If you are running Miktex DO NOT UPDATE AS ADMIN!

For some reasons I thought it is mandatory to update the packages with admin privileges. Miktex seems to have different package repositories for each user.

Comment: @kitingChris: Let use remove all unnecessary comments ;-)

Comment: @Marco most of them are off topic but users with same problems might find it useful to know...